# how to remove floating action button inflating exception in android?

Tags: android

I am using FAB(floating action button) in the app ,but it is making my life difficult from the past few days. Whenever I create new Project with single activity FAB work properly, but whenever I add new activities , it starts giving me exception

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.floating action button.
```

My xml code is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am using Appcompat theme as well and tried everything but problem remain the same.

Following is my Xml file for FAB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.vote3d.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            local:navigationIcon="@mipmap/ic_menu_36dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:background="#e00000"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <!-- <include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Following is the code I am using for FAB in class

```
   FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: where is `FloatingActionButton` code ??

Comment: I have updated the question, plz check it now

Answer (score 0):

**Use Below code For Floation Action Button in your XML**
**and do related changes**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

**if still it will gives the same error please provide Activity file and gradle file**

Answer (score 0):

please refer [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons). May be you must have missed something

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'` to your build.gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

Add "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" in your style.xml file